# How to disable a particular key press in .NET?

Tags: .net, event-handling, keyboard

I want to disable a particular key press in .NET(both VB.NET & C#.NET).``

Comment: You mean winforms and not webforms, right? 'cause otherwise this is more of a javascript question.

Comment: Do you not want an event to be fired on the KeyPress event and check if it is the particular key you pressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable a key globally (for all applications) by writing a [Global Key Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx), or just within your application using a [Local Key Hook](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=55895).

Once you have hooked the incoming keys, you can ignore particular ones and not pass them on to windows / to the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable for your own application only, You can also use [IMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx).